Accessing raw pointer when overloading -> operator on wrapped shared_ptr
I am working on a task to create an interop layer between two components, one living in the .NET world and one being C++ (20).
The layer is written in C++/CLI. I'm heavily making use of shared pointers, since they are most comfortable for me as a .NET dev (go easy on me, cpp world is kinda new to me).
Now I've stumbled upon a nice ref wrapper for shared pointers:
template<class T>
public ref class SharedPointer sealed
{
public:
    SharedPointer() : m_Ptr(new std::shared_ptr<T>()) {}

    SharedPointer(T* t)
    {
        m_Ptr = new std::shared_ptr<T>(t);
    }

    SharedPointer(std::shared_ptr<T> t)
    {
        m_Ptr = new std::shared_ptr<T>(t);
    }

    SharedPointer(const SharedPointer<T>% other)
    {
        m_Ptr = new std::shared_ptr<T>(*other.m_Ptr);
    }

    !SharedPointer()
    {
        delete pPtr;
    }

    ~SharedPointer()
    {
        this->!SharedPointer();
    }

    operator std::shared_ptr<T>() {
        return *m_Ptr;
    }

    SharedPointer<T>% operator=(T* ptr)
    {
        delete m_Ptr;
        m_Ptr = new std::shared_ptr<T>(ptr);
        return *this;
    }

    T* operator->() {
        return (*m_Ptr).get();
    }

    void reset()
    {
        m_Ptr->reset();
    }

    const std::shared_ptr<T>& get()
    {
        return *pPtr;
    }

    std::shared_ptr<T>* share()
    {
        return new std::shared_ptr<T>(*pPtr);
    }

    SharedPointer<T>% operator=(const std::shared_ptr<T>& t)
    {
        delete pPtr;
        pPtr = new std::shared_ptr<T>(t);
        return *this;
    }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<T>* m_Ptr;
};

Now there's one downside, which is - the C++ layer in this whole constructs wants raw pointers, hence I need to retreive it when passing as argument. However, as far as I understand the code, by overloading the -> operator, I omit access to the helper methods get(), share() & reset(). Which means the following does not work, because the method identifier is not recognized:
SharedPointer<CMessageUser>^ m_MessageUser = gcnew SharedPointer<CMessageUser>(new CMessageUser());

m_MessageInterface->Register(m_MessageUser->get()); // <- get() does not work, but I need raw pointer to CMessageUser

Am I going in a very wrong direction? Or is there an easy solution to this? Thanks in advance!

I don't know C++/CLI but do you really have to store a pointer to std::shared_ptr<T>?  Can't you just make it std::shared_ptr<T>?

No, managed classes unfortunately cannot have members of unmanaged types, hence, pointer
